# Accessing a List value from an Intvar

Tags: python, list, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create an example program for my high school class. The idea of the program is you can select a game (a basic version of Steam) from a selection of radiobuttons. The radiobuttons are linked to a IntVar stored in self.library_game. When you select a radiobutton I want to use the value that the radiobutton assigns the Intvar to take a name out of a list and display the name of the game in a label. I want to do this so I can use the IntVar to access other lists. The other lists will show things like the games installed status. if the game is not currently "installed" you will be able to click on a button to update the status to "install" the game so it can be "launched".

The problem i am encountering is: When I try and use the IntVar to access the libraryGames list I get the following error:"list indices must be integers or slices, not method". I have tried to store the value from the IntVar as a regular integer with "test=self.library_game.get" and used "test" to access the list, self.game_selection_label.configure(text = "You have chosen: " + str(libraryGames[test]),fg="#01fc07"),  but it doesn't work.

I am not the strongest programmer and am really pushing my ceiling with this stuff, so any help would be amazing.

```
from tkinter import*
# Variables and Lists
#Classes
libraryGames=["The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt GOTE", "Jurassic World: Evolution", "Red Dead Redemption 2","Mass Effect Trilogy","Subnautica"]
libraryGamesInstall=[True,False, False, False, False]

class SteamGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        #variables
        global libraryGames
        global libraryGamesInstall
        WD=800
        self.header =PhotoImage(file = "header.gif")
        self.library_game = IntVar()
        self.library_game.set = ()

        Title=Label(parent, image = self.header, width=WD, anchor=N)
        Title.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2, sticky=N,padx=2, pady=2)

        #User Library Menu
        frame1=Frame(bg="#000000",)
        frame1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky = 'w')

        library_label=Label(frame1, text="User Library",bg="#000000",fg="#01fc07",font=("Eras Demi ITC","40"),  anchor=N)
        library_label.grid(row=0, column=0,columnspan=2, sticky=N,padx=2, pady=2)

        radio1 = Radiobutton(frame1, variable = self.library_game, value = 0,text =libraryGames[0],
                             bg="#000000",fg="#ffffff",font=("Calibri","20"), command = self.library_choice)
        radio1.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'w')
        radio2 = Radiobutton(frame1, variable = self.library_game, value =1,text =libraryGames[1],
                             bg="#000000",fg="#ffffff",font=("Calibri","20"), command = self.library_choice)
        radio2.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'w')
        radio3 = Radiobutton(frame1, variable = self.library_game, value =2,text =libraryGames[2],
                             bg="#000000",fg="#ffffff",font=("Calibri","20"),command = self.library_choice)
        radio3.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'w')
        radio4 = Radiobutton(frame1, variable = self.library_game, value =3,text =libraryGames[3],
                             bg="#000000",fg="#ffffff",font=("Calibri","20"),command = self.library_choice)
        radio4.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'w')
        radio5 = Radiobutton(frame1, variable = self.library_game, value =4,text =libraryGames[4],
                             bg="#000000",fg="#ffffff",font=("Calibri","20"),command = self.library_choice)
        radio5.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky = 'w')

        self.game_selection_label=Label(frame1, text="No game selected", bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", width="50",)
        self.game_selection_label.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='w')

        self.game_install_status_label=Label(frame1, text="Install Status", bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", width="50",)
        self.game_install_status_label.grid(row=7, column=0, sticky='w', pady=10)

        self.playLabel =Label(frame1,text="Game Status", bg="#000000", fg="#ffffff", width="50", pady=10)
        self.playLabel.grid(row=9, column=0, sticky='w')

        installButton=Button(frame1, text="Install", width = 20, font=("Eras Demi ITC","10"), pady=10)
        installButton.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky = 'sw',)
        playButton=Button(frame1, text="Play", width = 20,font=("Eras Demi ITC","10"), pady=10)
        playButton.grid(row=8, column=0, sticky = 'se',)




        frame2=Frame(bg="#ffffff",)
        frame2.grid(row=1, column=1)

    def library_choice(self):
        test=0
        test=self.library_game.get
        print("hi", self.library_game.get)
        self.game_selection_label.configure(text = "You have chosen: " + str(libraryGames[test]),fg="#01fc07")
                #self.game_selection_label.configure(text = "You have chosen: The witcher 3!!!!!",fg="#01fc07")


#Main Routine
root=Tk()
window = SteamGUI(root)
root.geometry("800x700+0+0")
root.title("Steam Basic")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `.get()`, not `.get`. `get` is the *name* of the method, but you're not actually executing anything. In other words, `test` in your code is being set to the name of some function, not the output of that function. You want the actual integer value, so you want the output of the function.

Comment: Thankyou!!!!!! I have spent more time than i would like to admit trying to figure it out